# datatable not update from a commandbutton when other commandbutton have oncomplete="tb1.clearfilter()"

Tags: primefaces

datatable not update when commandbutton2 clic while commandbutton1 have oncomplete="tb1.clearfilter(), the commandButton1 reload the datatable list from backingbean "firmarFacturaMB" and call the client side method clearfilter for datatable tb1,
When I select an item and set a requires value datatable must be reload witout the selected item but it is not happend, only work the commandButton1 never pressed. This is code:

```
<h:form id="frm1">
        <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true" />
        <p:panel header="Firmar facturas" style="border-width: 0px"
            id="panel1">
            <p:commandButton oncomplete="tb1.clearfilter() value="
                Recargar" update=":frm1:growl :frm1:panel1" icon="ui-icon-refresh"
                actionListener="#{firmarFacturaMB.buscarFacturasSinFirmar}" />

            <p:dataTable emptyMessage="No se encontraron elementos"
                widgetVar="tb1" id="tablaFact" var="item"
                selection="#{firmarFacturaMB.selectedFactura}"
                selectionMode="single" paginator="true" rows="20"
                rowKey="#{item.idFactura}"
                value="#{firmarFacturaMB.facturaUtilList}"
                filteredValue="#{firmarFacturaMB.filterFacturaUtilList}">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                    update=":frm1:growl :frm1:panelDetallesServicio"
                    oncomplete="servDialog.show()"
                    listener="#{firmarFacturaMB.buscarDetallesFactura}" />
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update=":frm1:growl" />

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Listado de facturas sin firmar " />
                </f:facet>

                <p:column style="width:10%" sortBy="#{item.noFactura}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Nro" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.noFactura}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
            <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Detalles de la factura"
                widgetVar="servDialog" resizable="false">
                <p:panel id="panelDetallesServicio" style="border: 0px;">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Seleccione la fecha de firma: *"
                            style="font-size: 12px" />
                        <p:calendar value="#{firmarFacturaMB.fechaFirma}"
                            id="popupButtonCal1" showOn="button" required="true" locale="es"
                            effect="show" showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true" />
                        <p:commandButton value="Firmar" update=":frm1:growl :frm1"
                            actionListener="#{firmarFacturaMB.firmarFactura}"
                            icon="ui-icon-pencil" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </p:dialog>
        </p:panel>

</h:form>
```

Comment: Where is your `commandbutton2` ? I am also not getting `When I select an item and set a requires value datatable must be reload witout the selected item but it is not happend, only work the commandButton1 never pressed`. Please make your question clear.

Comment: commandbutton1 is the firsh button, commandbutton 2 is inside dialog. When commandbutton1 is pressed reload datatable fine but after when comandbutton2 is pressed dont refresh datatable. If i delete oncomplete="tb1.clearfilter() from commandbutton1 then every thing work ok.